# Media Center Remote Control : how can I configure the 4 colors buttons?

Tags: windows-media-center, remote

How can I configure the 4 colors buttons that came with the Windows remote for Media Center? I have searched on the web and in all menus without seeing anything about it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Media Control](http://damienbt.free.fr/) makes use of them, plugin developers need to jump through some serious hoops to access them. The hoops are full of fire and involve working through a lot of undocumented stuff. So its quite rare to see these buttons used.

They are completely unconfigurable out-of-the-box and have a very restrictive teletext use, a feature which most people do not use.

Answer (score 0):

I think those are Fastext-buttons for services like Teletext or CeeFax (BBC) where they function as shortcuts to pages

To use the Fastext buttons

The red, green, yellow, and blue buttons on your remote control correspond to the
same colored buttons on your TV. Press a colored button on your remote control
to go to a preset page. For example, on page 100, press the green button on the
remote control to go to the New Zealand News Index, or Page 102.